# Comments that are just a link are non-deletable on mobile

Tags: support, comments, ios-app, comment-flags

On the Stack Exchange iPhone app, to bring up the small menu beneath a comment with delete, reply, etc., we touch an area of text within the comment (touching a name or link will navigate to the commenter’s profile or URL respectively)

But when a comment is *just* a URL, there appears to be nowhere to touch the comment in order to bring up the menu (since it will navigate to the URL). Hence the comment cannot be deleted, flagged, etc.

Example below

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Are you using the ios app?

Comment: @Spevacus yes, iOS app on iPhone 8

Comment: @Spevacus ah, very interesting. Thanks for letting me know. I’ll use the browser as suggested there

Comment: No problem. It is a bit unfortunate, but the mobile apps are just not being maintained anymore. Your time spent reporting this bug is appreciated, but unfortunately, it'll never be fixed. The responsive website is pretty passable, though!

Comment: What do you mean by "Example below"? Is something missing?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q  it’s in reference to the first comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to tap on the left, where the score for the comment would be:

[image: Screenshot with left of link comment circled]

(Works no matter if you posted the comment or not.)

Comment: All this time I had no idea. Thank you!